# nested newcommand to create randomized test

Tags: macros, random

Ok, so I have basically learned LaTex by reading some package manuals and finding answers to specific questions on this site.  I have been creating randomized versions of written math exams using the eqexam package and newcommand to define problems.  For example, one problem is set up as follows:

```
\newcommand{\CreditPayoffQuestion}[1]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
    \def\ops{{"1225","1475","1175","1350","1250"}}
    \def\opsa{{"14.99","15.99","16.99","17.99"}}
    \def\opsb{{"60","65","70","75","80","85"}}
    \newcommand\randomopone{\bgroup\pgfmathsetmacro\op{\ops[int(rnd*5)]}\op\egroup}
    \newcommand\randomoptwo{\bgroup\pgfmathsetmacro\op{\opsa[int(rnd*4)]}\op\egroup}
    \newcommand\randomopthree{\bgroup\pgfmathsetmacro\op{\opsb[int(rnd*6)]}\op\egroup}
    $\text{Assume you want to buy a new phone that costs }\$\randomopone{}\text{ using a credit card that has an APR}\\ \text{of }\randomoptwo{}\%\text{. How long will it take you to pay off the phone if you make regular monthly}\\ \text{payments of }\$\randomopthree{}\text{.  Round your answer to the nearest tenth of a year.}$%
    }%
}%
```

When I compile: 5. \CreditPayoffQuestion{1} I get what I expect:
[image: correct versioning of problem]

So now the problem. I have six different versions of a table that I am defining, such as:

```
\newcommand{\TableA}{\begin{tabular}{|llr|}
        \hline \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Statement for May 15-June 14}\\
        \hline Previous Balance:&&\$180\\
        \hline May 20&Payment&\$225\\
        \hline Charges:&&\\
        &May 16&\$70\\
        &May 25&\$156\\
        &June 5&\$85\\
        \hline Days in Billing Cycle&&31\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
```

I am trying to randomly pick one of these to insert into a problem to get something that looks like:
[image: TableA]

I have used the code:

```
\newcommand*{\CreditTableQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {#1,...,##1}{%
        \def\opsb{{"\TableA","\TableB","\TableC","\TableD","\TableE","\TableF"}}
        \newcommand\randomopone{\bgroup\pgfmathsetmacro\op{\opsb[int(rnd*4)]}\op\egroup}
        $\randomopone{}$%
    }%
}%
```

but keep getting the errors:

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgffor@values. \CreditTableQuestion{1}

and

Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 316

Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Before or reinvent the wheel and the car, I would look if I could be interested in AMC (for Debian like distros, just type `sudo apt  install auto-multiple-choice`).

Comment: `\newcommand*{\CreditTableQuestion}[1]{\foreach \i in {#1,...,##1}...` - what is `##1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the random number generators in `expl3` that also provides for simpler syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\optionlists}{m}
 {% each set of options is of the form {label}{item1,item2,...}
  \bowman_random_optionlists:n { #1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randopt}{m}
 {% #1 is one of the previously set up labels
  \bowman_random_getrandom:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__bowman_random_options_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bowman_random_optionlists:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__bowman_random_options_tl { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \bowman_random_getrandom:n
 {
  \bowman_random_get:e
   {
    \str_case:nV { #1 } \l__bowman_random_options_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { nV }

\cs_new:Nn \bowman_random_get:n
 {
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { \int_rand:n { \clist_count:n { #1 } } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bowman_random_get:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\optionlists{
  {}{1225,1475,1175,1350,1250}
  {a}{14.99,15.99,16.99,17.99}
  {b}{60,65,70,75,80,85}
  {c}{TableA,TableB,TableC}
}


\newcommand{\CreditPayoffQuestion}[1]{%
  Assume you want to buy a new phone that costs \$\randopt{} using a credit card 
  that has an APR of \randopt{a}. How long will it take you to pay off the phone
  if you make regular monthly payments of \$\randopt{b}?  Round your answer to
  the nearest tenth of a year.

  Comment the following table

  \UseName{\randopt{c}}
}

\newcommand{\TableA}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}Table & A \\ 1 & 2 \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\TableB}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}Table & B \\ 3 & 4 \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\TableC}{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}Table & C \\ 5 & 6 \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}

\CreditPayoffQuestion

\bigskip

\CreditPayoffQuestion

\end{document}
```

You can define any number of lists to which choose from and do it in a centralized fashion rather than in each question producing command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just want to condition on using `\TableA`...`\TableF` based on some random variable. The following does that, using the functionality provided by [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp)'s `rand()` and converting that to an alphabetic character via `\@Alph`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\TableA}{This is Table~A}
\newcommand{\TableB}{This is Table~B}
\newcommand{\TableC}{This is Table~C}
\newcommand{\TableD}{This is Table~D}
\newcommand{\TableE}{This is Table~E}
\newcommand{\TableF}{This is Table~F}

\begin{document}

\csname Table\csname @Alph\endcsname{\fpeval{ceil(6*rand())}}\endcsname

\end{document}
```